# How do I map to a Drive within my 'Java Program' if it Prompts for a 'Username' and 'password'?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

How do I map to a Drive within my Java Program if it Prompts for a Username and password?

For example I have a java program which conducts the following:

1. Code creates an empty folder to contain documents
2. Currently the folder successfully gets created within the C: drive which is my local machine.

**3. But how do i map to a drive within my java program and in turn create a folder within that location if it prompts for the username and password (I have the relevant credentials to access the drive)**

Example drive need to map to: \19x.1xx.1.3x\c$

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you want to access a smb share using java?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @f1sh yes this is a shared drive only accessible via username and password, for example if i map to the drive from windows with: start > run > drive location > enter username & password = im able to access the drive, but how can i access the drive via my java program?

Comment: @f1sh thanks i will look into the details listed within the link